# how to pull out array of string values from a deserialized JSON response

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

I am pretty new to coding and here is my requirement:

- I am getting a **JSON** response which has an array of values (refer read,update,delete in the below **JSON** response)
- The number of values is dynamic and tend to vary each time.
- I want to know how to retrieve them and put into an string array and return the values

Eg.: end result should be like

```
string[] deleteValues = {"MCS:Menu:Admin","MCS:test"}
```

In case if there is answer already available to this question, please point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

==========================================

I am able to get the values this way...

```
string value1 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<JSON_Deconstructor>(resp).Permitted[0].Delete[0].ToString();

string value2 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<JSON_Deconstructor>(resp).Permitted[0].Delete[1].ToString();
```

but since the number of values in delete is dynamic, i need to how to pull them.

====================

the code snippet:

```
string resp = new StreamReader(request1.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd(); // resp is a JSON response from a server
JSON_Deconstructor dc = new JSON_Deconstructor { };
dc.Permitted = new Permitted[1];

string value1 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<JSON_Deconstructor>(resp).Permitted[0].Delete[0].ToString();

string value2 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<JSON_Deconstructor>(resp).Permitted[0].Delete[1].ToString();
```

==================

JSON_Deconstructor class contents:

```
public class JSON_Deconstructor
{
    public Permitted[] Permitted { get; set; }
    public Denied[] Denied { get; set; }
}
```

==================

Permitted class contents:

```
public class Permitted
{
    public string[] Read { get; set; }
    public string[] Update { get; set; }
    public string[] Delete { get; set; }
}
```

=================

JSON response:

```
{
"Permitted": [
    {
        "read": [
            "MCS:Menu:Admin"
        ],
        "update": [
            "MCS:test"
        ],
        "delete": [
            "MCS:Menu:Admin",
            "MCS:test"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Please add an example of what you want to do.

Comment: Use `forach()`? What do you want to do with the values?

Comment: @itdoesntwork I have edited with an example of how I want the end result

Comment: Would parsing JSON into .NET object, modifying it (you could do whatever you want in the code with such object, delete whatever you want, etc), and then serialising it back into JSON work for you?

Usually, you have an input and an output model (.NET objects). You parse JSON into the input model convert it to the output model and then serialize it back to JSON. The input and output models should correspond to an input/output JSON.

Comment: @CodeCaster, uhhh.. can you show me how to use that in this context ?

Comment: @Aditia, could you also clarify what `no.` is?

Comment: @PavelSapehin it is abbreviation for number of values
I wrote "no." instead of "number of"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add jsonProperty to your class in order to be able to serialize.

```
public class Permitted
{
    [JsonProperty("read")]
    public string[] Read { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("update")]
    public string[] Update { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("delete")]
    public string[] Delete { get; set; }
}

//Response contains a list of permitted objects in Permitted property
public class PermittedResponse
{
    public List<Permitted> Permitted { get; set; }
}
```

then in you method de serialize your response and loop through results to build your arrays.

```
List<string> deletedValues = new List<string>();
List<string> readValues = new List<string>();
List<string> updateValues = new List<string>();

PermittedResponse response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PermittedResponse>(serializedJson);

response.Permitted.ForEach(e =>
   {
        deletedValues = deletedValues.Concat(e.Delete).ToList();
        readValues = readValues.Concat(e.Read).ToList();
        updateValues = updateValues.Concat(e.Update ).ToList();
   });
```

Comment: what reference do I need to add inorder for me to use JsonProperty & JsonConvert ?

Comment: google is your friend..
Use these for this example
"using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;"

Comment: I tried but I am getting an error "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Testing_MDP.Permitted]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly."

Comment: updated answer.. your response object was different that the mapping i provided. please try again

Comment: THANK YOU SIR!!! it worked smooth... however I had to change e.Delete in the other two places for capturing other values. LoL :)
but the code was right on target.

Comment: your are welcome. it is just a guide.. there are better ways to do it. feel free to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Use Newtonsoft.Json. You can get it from  NuGet. This is very simple and powerful library for Json.

Now, you should create a class, like:

```
public class Item
{
    public List<string> MCS { get; set; } = new List<string>();
} 

public class PermitedItem
{
    public Item read {get; set;}
    public Item update {get; set;}
    public Item delete {get; set;}
}
public class MyResponse
{
    public List<PermittedItem> Permitted = new List<PermittedItems>();
}
```

And then you use it like that:

```
MyResponse result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyResponse>(jsonAsString);
```

This should work.

Comment: Sure, JSON.NET is a more convenient API than JavaScriptSerializer, but that has nothing to do with the question of how to read nested arrays.

Comment: You don't have to do anything special with JSON.NET, because it does everything by itself. You have to just create correct classes. That's all.